# how to call sub from another sub(Still Same form) in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

i have piece of code below :

```
Public Sub dgvPenjualan_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgvPenjualan.CurrentCellChanged
    Dim jumlahrow As Integer = dgvPenjualan.RowCount()
    'Dim nama As String
    Dim jumlahtotal As Integer = 0
    Dim harga, jumlah As String
    Dim total As Integer
    'Dim indeks As Integer and bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

and `dgvPenjualan_CurrentCellChanged` sub from another sub ? 
anybody can help me ? please

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Please rephrase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code inside `dgvPenjualan_CurrentCellChanged` does not use the parameters `sender` and/or `e`, then you can call it from anywhere in your project using:

```
dgvPenjualan_CurrentCellChanged(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Otherwise, you will need to pass the parameters as well:

```
dgvPenjualan_CurrentCellChanged(dgvPenjualan, New System.EventArgs())
```